# java.lang.AbstractMethodError - while using ANT Built jar

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, interface, abstract

I'm getting `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`for a specific case (only when I create a jar of my classes with ant) and I can't get my head around it. Some help to understand this would be much appreciated.

Consider the following case (for some reason I've to keep the class hierarchy in my code as its below in example and I think doing so should not give me an AbstractMethodError in any case!):

```
 public interface Cat {
     void speak();
 }

 public interface ColoredHeadCat extends Cat {
     boolean isColoredHead();
 }

 public interface RedHeadCat extends ColoredHeadCat {
     boolean isRedHead();
 }

 public interface SuperRedCat extends RedHeadCat {
     boolean isSuperCat();
 }

 public abstract class AbstractCat {
     public void speak() {
         System.out.println("Meow!");
     }
 }

 public abstract class AbstractColoredHeadCat extends AbstractCat {
     // .. Not overriding speak() method here

     public boolean isColoredHead() {
         return true;
    }
 }

 public abstract class AbstractRedHeadCat extends AbstractColoredHeadCat {
     // .. Not overriding speak() method here

     public boolean isRedHead() { 
         return true;
     }
 }

 public class SuperRedHeadCat extends AbstractRedHeadCat implements SuperRedCat {
     // .. Not overriding speak() method here too

     public  boolean isSuperCat() {
         return true;
     }
 }

 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] arrgh) {
         SuperRedHeadCat superCat = new SuperRedHeadCat();
         superCat.speak(); // No exceptions! Works like charm.

         Cat cat = new SuperRedHeadCat();
         cat.speak(); // Gives java.lang.AbstractMethodError! Why?
     }
 }
```

All classes are in the same package.

So the problem is I can't reproduce this through Eclipse: Everything runs perfectly. But after building a jar with `ant`, and then running 'Main' it throws `AbstractMethodError`. I'm out of ideas here about the reason for this behavior.

**java -version**

> java version "1.6.0_27"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)

**ant -version**

> Apache Ant version 1.8.0 compiled on February 1 2010

P.S.: Except the `Main` class, remaining classes are obfuscated during ant build.
**This problem is as resolved if I let `AbstractCat` implement `Cat` interface , `AbstractColoredHeadCat` implement `ColoredHeadCat` interface and `AbstractRedHeadCat` implement `RedHeadCat` interface.**

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace of the error

Comment: It's obfuscated, would it help?

Comment: Should be a bit :) , The problem is that you are referring some class in your main , which ultimately gets around . if possible can you try not obfuscating and running the jar

Comment: You may decompile your obfuscated code to see what happends

Comment: This sounds like it's a problem with the Ant build.  Have you tried manually building on the command line using `javac`?

Comment: @AkashYadav Since this is just a parallel sample of my actual code (it's very big). I'll try and get the stack trace for the example above if it's of some help. And removing obfuscation from the ant build would be a bit difficult for me right now :(.

Comment: @OlegPavliv I tried decompiling the obfuscated jar and I think with the obfuscated names I could make out that `SuperRedHeadCat` is properly inheriting the `speak()` method. So not a problem there I think.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope, didn't try manually building on the command line yet! I'll try if I can and post update here.

Answer (score 0):

Which obfuscator are you using?

I tried with yguard and it works fine:

```
<taskdef name="obfuscate" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask"  classpath="c:/Soft/Java/yguard-2.5.3/lib/yguard.jar" />
<target name="obf" depends="jar">
    <obfuscate >
        <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
        <inoutpair in="target/cat.jar" out="target/obf.jar"/>

        <shrink >
            <property name="error-checking" value="pedantic"/>
            <keep>
                <method name="void main(java.lang.String[])" class="Main"/>
            </keep>
        </shrink>

        <rename mainclass="Main">
            <expose >
                <class classes="public" methods="public" fields="public">
                    <patternset>
                        <include name="**.*"/>
                        <exclude name="Main"/>
                    </patternset>
                </class>
            </expose>
        </rename>
    </obfuscate>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm using RetroGuard ( :( ). I'm trying to pull out the code (from my project) which is causing that error and take an obfuscated ant build. Thanks though for trying this out with YGuard. Good to know it's working with YGuard.